# Debian - No WiFi after fresh install

Tags: debian, wifi

I just installed Debian Stretch on my System. I had to load all the drivers on another USB stick in order to get the WiFi-stick working, but when it finally accepted the USB, I had internet while installing.

After the first reboot however, I get an error message, that I can't connect to my WiFi. So I look into the settings, but nothing seems wrong. I re-type my password and see, that the "Save" button is greyed out. It says: "Invalid setting Wi-Fi: invalid MAC adress...". Sure enough, it says "permanent" in the field where you can enter your MAC adress. So I empty that field out, but the re-connect still fails. I just get the spinner and it eventually gives up:

[image: Not connecting]

ifconfig outputs:

```
enp4s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 8c:89:a5:88:02:d0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 39476  bytes 2368560 (2.2 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 39476  bytes 2368560 (2.2 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx7cdd905ca7ad: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 4e:6d:39:55:9c:99  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and my wlan config looks like this:

[image: My wlan config]

I also tried manual connection as described in debian wiki wiki.debian[dot]org WiFi HowToUse, but `ifup wlx7cdd905ca7ad` just outputs:

```
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
Failed to bring up wlx7cdd905ca7ad.
```

[EDIT:]

As requested:

lspci (not important since its an USB device) but lsusb: `Realink Tech, corp RT5370 Wireless adapter`

`lsmod | grep wifi`:  (nothing)

`ls -s /lib/firmware/`:

`4 hp   8 rt2870.bin   4 rtl_nic`

[EDIT2:]

`lsmod | grep rt`:

```
iTCO_vendor_support    16384  1 iTCO_wdt
rt2800usb              28672  0
rt2x00usb              24576  1 rt2800usb
rt2800lib              94208  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              53248  3 rt2x00usb,rt2800lib,rt2800usb
mac80211              643072  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb,rt2800lib
cfg80211              569344  2 mac80211,rt2x00lib
crc_ccitt              16384  1 rt2800lib
parport_pc             28672  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
usbcore               241664  9 uas,rt2x00usb,usb_storage,rt2800usb,ehci_hcd,ehci_pci,usbhid,xhci_hcd,xhci_pci
```

`networkctl`:

```
IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP     
  1 lo               loopback           n/a         unmanaged 
  2 enp4s0           ether              n/a         unmanaged 
  3 wlx7cdd905ca7ad  wlan               n/a         unmanaged 

3 links listed.
```

Comment: Include in your question output of `#lspci` , output of `#lsmod |grep wifi ` and output of `#ls -l /lib/firmware/`. Make sure that you have the required firmware for your wifi adapter installed.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou firmware is definitely there, since it worked while installing. it's just not connecting anymore. (btw added requested info)

Comment: yes, run `lsmod |grep rt`  and also have a look here that covers your WiFi adapter: https://wiki.debian.org/rt2800usb

Comment: @Theophrastus but I can scan WiFi just fine! either way. `lsmod | grep rt` displays several realtech drivers. rt2800 is there (debians WiFi wiki says I need this lib for this chip). However I switched USB cards, installed drivers for the new one as well (since the wiki said that support for rt2800 is bad) but that didn't work either :(  (I had a RT2501/ RT2573 and wiki says it's "bad" too...)

Comment: @Theophrastus I don't think so. As I said it's a fresh installation. I installed nothing yet... And I just tried connecting to an open hotspot. didn't work either... (so "wrong password" is not the cause either). But how can I check what network managers I have installed?

Comment: @Theophrastus I'll try that tomorrow morning. It's quite late (or should I say early) in Europe :D

Comment: Can you show `networkctl` too?

Comment: @Bahamut @Theophrastus Added complete `lsmod | grep rt` and `networkctl` as requested

Comment: The linkname for your wlan card is strange.  `dmesg | egrep -i 'net|err|fail|firm'` and `journalctl -b -u wpa_supplicant` `lsusb | egrep -i 'ether|wlan'`

Comment: I'm getting the same issue right now setting up a machine for my niece...

Comment: I had issues with this after a recent install of stretch with a mediatek 7601 micro-usb. I connected it to the internet via another adapter and it fixed the issue through update. I'm unsure how helpful that is, but it made me happy.

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable the random MAC address randomization :
add the following to your /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and restart NetworkManager.service:

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

See
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=836351
and
https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/55ltct/stretch_wifi_issues/

CB